# How to create a string that can produce audio on specific word pressed

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode

I Have a long text with UITextView which I modify with NSAttributedString and with symbols

so for example:

```
"""
if it works like
$I want$
it
will be awesome
"""
```

"I want" will be presented as bold, because I mark bold font with $...$

I have a method that receives a string and starts a for-in loop.
when it finds the $ sign, it starts to count the start index and the end index.
when it finishes counting I use :

```
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: 
 boldFont, range: NSMakeRange(start, end))
```

but now I came to a dead end. how can I make the same exact string to produce sound when I tap on him.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned this string you are adding in TextView, You mentioned you want to play some sound whenever you click "I want" let me make it more clear, you need to add link attribute in your string. Let me show you a simple example. you can translate to the swift,

```
  NSString* description = @"if it works like @% it will be awesome";
  NSString* clickAbleStr = @"I want";
  NSString* detail = [NSString stringWithFormat:description,clickAbleStr];

  NSMutableAttributedString *linkStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:detail attributes:nil];
 [linkStr addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:NSLocalizedString(@"http://www.googl.com", @"") range:[detail rangeOfString:clickAbleStr]];
 [linkStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:[detail rangeOfString:clickAbleStr]];
 yourtextview.attributedText = linkStr;

 yourtextview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [yourtextview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)]];

- (void)tapAction:(id)sender {
  // implement tap action for sound
}
```

Comment: can you provide a swift version?

so if I want to create a selector method I need to provide it a random link?